# Working on a random challenge, but having a problem with

Tags: java, loops, nested

//Java nested loop, if the user input less than 1 and Great than 11 it must display error message. Implementing java nested for loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        if (size < 1 && size > 11)
            System.out.println("INVALID NUMBERS");

        for (int rows = size; size > 0; rows++) {
            for (int colums = size; colums < 11; colums++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Tags

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(size<1 && size>11)
```

size can not both be less than 1 AND greater than 11.

You'll need a logical OR here:

```
if(size<1 || size>11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but to my understanding this is what you're looking for?

```
  int size=input.nextInt(); 
  if(size<1 || size>11) {
   System.out.println("INVALID NUMBERS");
  }
   else{
    for (int rows=size;size>0;rows++){ 
      for(int colums=size;colums<11;colums++){ 
        System.out.print("#"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is okay, I just figure out that my structure is not right.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all question is not very elaborative and does not mention what the end result should look like.

To my understanding, this code will result in infinite loop when size entered is greater than 0, because of the line:-
for (int rows = size; size > 0; rows++) , the loop will be infinite because the test condition is always greater than zero.